# add_10 layer missing within resnet50 model error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, valueerror

My code had a get_layer command with the layer being add_10 which seems to now be gone from resnet50

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-daf2397b330f> in <cell line: 33>()
     31 
     32 inputs = model.get_layer('input_1').output
---> 33 x = model.get_layer('add_10').output
     34 x = AveragePooling2D((14,14), name='new_ap')(x)
     35 x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
```

`

I checked the layers using model.summary() and could no longer find the layer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This layer is from the 1.9 tf version and I was wondering what the updated command would be